# Code metrics in TFS 2015 Build

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, build-automation, tfs-2015

Do we have any option to display code metrics details in TFS 2015 on-prem build? 
I couldn't find any option to include the values as part of build. Ideally I would like to display the values below code coverage section (as show in pic).
[image]

Something similar to this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamiedalton/2014/06/12/visual-studio-2013-code-metrics-and-tfs-builds/

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1230/build-customization-code-metrics-utility-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 2):

In Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 or later, your goal can be achieved. You can write your own [TFS extensions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/team-foundation-server-extensions-2/) to enable integration at the UI layer – surfacing the relevant information in the right places. Check Overview of extensions for TFS/VSTS: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview

Good resources to start using Extension:

- https://github.com/RobertK66/vsts-opencover
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples